# How can I get webpack to find angular modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0

I'm trying to setup a bare-bones application with Angular 1 + Typescript 2 and Webpack. The app works fine until I try to use an external module, ex: `angular-ui-router`.

It always complains that it can't find the dependency:

`ERROR in ./src/app.ts Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular-ui-router' in ./src/app.ts 3:26-54`

Demo showing problem: https://github.com/jxc876/angular-ts

I suspect I'm not importing the routing dependency correctly, tried:

- `import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';`
- `import * as uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router'`

Tried with `angular-route` and also `ui-router` but neither works. Tried `ts-loader` and `awesome-typescript-loader`.

## App

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

let myApp = angular.module('myApp', [uiRouter]);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  let homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    template: '<div>It works !!!</div>'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(homeState);
});
```

## Config

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ts-demo",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base ./src"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.16",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.34",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "typescript": "^2.0.9",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "listFiles": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657652/webpack-with-typescript-external-commonjs-module/34658780

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally figured this out.

First issue is that the typescript compiler removes import statements that are not used.

> The compiler detects whether each module is used in the emitted JavaScript. If a module identifier is only ever used in type annotations and never as an expression then no require call is emitted for that module. This culling of unused references is a good performance optimization, and also allows for optional loading of those modules.

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4717

I assigned the imported value to a dummy array and it seems to fix this. Logging the value out to the console also works. (See my final note on why I couldn't simply pass it into the dependency array).

EDIT: Better solution is to use `import "module"; syntax` since that is always emitted based on the github above, ex: `import 'angular-ui-router';`

---

Second, my webpack file was missing an empty string in the resolve array:

`resolve { extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'] }`

Without this it couldn't pull in the file for ui router.

A few things I noticed while working on this: `webpack --display-error-details` is super useful. For some reason it was looking for double `.js.js` extensions inside `node_modules/angular-ui-router/release`:

```
resolve file
  /Users/mich2264/projects/angular-ts/node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js.ts doesn't exist
  /Users/mich2264/projects/angular-ts/node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js.js doesn't exist
```

`--traceResolution` is equally useful for typescript.

EDIT: Appears to be a awesome-typescript-loader loader bug: 
https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/pull/264

---

Finally, I'm not sure why but when I import the default value from `angular-ui-router` and I log it or set a breakpoint it shows up correctly as `ui.router`, but if I attempt to pass it into the dependency array it becomes undefined.

`@types/angular-ui-router` defines the following export inside their type file : `export default "ui.router";`

Answer (score 7):

This one should do the job:

```
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';

let myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

Notice, that import is just importing router code and in application module you need to inject `'ui.router'` string.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that since I'm using [UI-Router for AngularJS (1.x)](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/), I had to use...

```
import '@uirouter/angularjs'
```

...instead of...

```
import 'angular-ui-router'
```